# IT Asset Management

Tags: asset-management

Our company has grown quite quickly and I am facing new tasks which I did not think I'd need to deal with. Recently we've come ot a point where we have 100+ Devices (Routers, Bridges, Computers, Laptops, VOIP Phones etc). The other day I was quite frightened when I asked for an inventory and no one had one.

I want to start tagging all equipment and recording serials to begin tracking our inventory and ensuring we have a proper record of what equipment we have. Does anyone have advice as to how to go about 1. Convincing the higher ups why we need to do this and 2. What software or strategies might work?

Keep in mind this is not for furniture, office equipment etc but IT specific equipment. I'm concerned over people 1. Stealing the physical devices and 2. Losing track of configuration data etc in case we'd need to do a wipe and restore

Comment: Please move this to Server Fault.

Comment: While asset tracking is in a broad sense related to IT Security, I agree that it is something much more generally applicable to Server Administration.  I concur with @SteveSyfus' recommendation to move to SF.

Comment: http://www.govinfosecurity.com/whitepapers.php?wp_id=406 ... a good whitepaper that covers the subject (and tools) in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell the boss you need to track illegal software (because of fines) and which equipment is on warranty (to spare money on fixing) and you need tracking asset so people can't steal it.

On the software side I use, happily, the lovely (and free) Spiceworks :)